# How to filter users with a joined table where the values for the 'blocked' field will be either 1, 0, or NULL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I currently have two tables:

**Users**

id,

etc....

**Connections**

user_id_1

user_id_2

blocked

*where user_id_1 is the following user, and user_id_2 is the follower user (in the model of Twitter)*

---

I'm currently modifying my internal messaging system to allow all users to message all other users, with the only limitation being that if User A messages User B, but User B has blocked User A, the message will not go through.

With that in mind, have a look at this query:

```
SELECT u.id, IFNULL(c.blocked, 0) AS blocked
FROM cms_users u
    LEFT JOIN cms_connections c ON u.id=c.user_id_2 AND c.user_id_1=71
WHERE u.id IN (62, 65, 89, 90)
```

The idea here is that User 71 is trying to message users 62, 65, 89, and 90. User 71 is following 62, 65, and 89, but is not following 90. However, User 89 has blocked User 71. This means there are entries on the connections table that look like this:

```
user_id_1       user_id_2       blocked
71              62              0
71              65              0
71              89              1
```

When I run this query, I get this result:

```
user_id_1       blocked
62              0
65              0
89              1
90              0
```

This is exactly what I expect, however if I change the WHERE clause to look like this:

```
WHERE u.id IN (62, 65, 89, 90) AND blocked=0
```

Then I get this:

```
user_id_1       blocked
62              0
65              0
```

This is confusing to me because I'm expecting three rows: the two above and the one for User 90. I've also tried doing a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING blocked!=1` and `HAVING blocked=0` and they all produce the same result. I've also tried changing the name of the created column to `block` or `herpderp` just to check if there was a conflict with my JOIN, but that produced the same result.

Curious to see what you guys can come up with :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to `IFNULL(c.blocked, 0)`

```
SELECT u.id, 
       Ifnull(c.blocked, 0) AS blocked 
FROM   cms_users u 
       LEFT JOIN cms_connections c 
         ON u.id = c.user_id_2 
            AND c.user_id_1 = 71 
WHERE  u.id IN ( 62, 65, 89, 90 ) 
       AND Ifnull(c.blocked, 0) = 0
```

This query can be improved if rewritten into

```
SELECT u.id, 
       Ifnull(c.blocked, 0) AS blocked 
FROM   cms_users u 
       LEFT JOIN cms_connections c 
         ON c.user_id_1 = 71  
            AND u.id = c.user_id_2 
       JOIN (SELECT 62 AS uu 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT 65 AS uu 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT 89 AS uu 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT 90 AS uu) d 
         ON u.id = d.uu 
WHERE  Ifnull(c.blocked, 0) = 0
```

You need indexes on

- (cms_users.id)
- (cms_connections.user_id_1,cms_connections.user_id_2,cms_connections.user_id_2.blocked)

Answer (score 1):

Try: HAVING IFNULL(c.blocked,0) = 0